# How to test yargs application using Jest (Javascript/Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, yargs

I already asked the question on Jest repository [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11367). And also pushed a sample application [here](https://github.com/akefirad/test-yargs-jest) to reproduce the behavior. But for the sake of completeness here's the full story:
Essentially it's like this (`./parsers.ts`):

```js
import yargs from "yargs";

export const parser = yargs
  .strict(true)
  .help()
  .commandDir("cmds")
  .demandCommand(1)
  .recommendCommands();
```

And in `cmds` folder, there's a `remote.ts`:

```js
import { Argv } from "yargs";

export const command = "remote <command>";
export const describe = "Manage set of tracked repos";
export const handler = (yargs: Argv<any>) => {};
export const builder = (yargs: Argv<any>) => {
  return yargs
    .commandDir("remote_cmds")
    .demandCommand(1, 1)
    .recommendCommands();
};
```

And then there's `add.ts`:

```js
import { Argv } from "yargs";

export const command = "add <name> <url>";
export const handler = (yargs: Argv<any>): void => {};
export const describe = "Add remote named <name> for repo at url <url>";
export const builder = (yargs: Argv<any>): Argv => {
  return yargs.demandCommand(0, 0);
};
```

Now I've got two more files:

```js
// index.ts
import { parser } from "./parsers";
import { Arguments } from "yargs";

parser.parse("remote add foo", (err, argv, output) => {
  console.log("parsed argv: %s", JSON.stringify(argv));
  if (err) console.log("ERROR\n" + err);
  if (output) console.log("OUTPUT\n" + output);
});
```

When I run this, it fails, rightly so. Because `remote add` command expects two arguments. And if I pass correct input, it gives correct output. Meaning everything works just fine.

```js
// parsers.test.ts
import { Arguments } from "yargs";
import { parser } from "./parsers";

describe("remote", () => {
  test("add", async () => {
    const argv = parser.parse("remote add foo", (err, argv, output) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(argv));
      if (err) console.log("ERROR\n" + err);
      if (output) console.log("OUTPUT\n" + output);
    });
    expect(argv.name).toEqual("foo");
  });
});
```

Also the Jest configuration is:

```js
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  testEnvironment: "node",
  testRegex: "./src/.*\\.(test|spec)?\\.(ts|ts)$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
};
```

But when I run the above test, it doesn't fail at all, as if the parser has no configuration. (The assertion interestingly fails because `foo` is not extracted as a property into `argv` which shows, again, the parser didn't pick up the configuration inside `cmds` folder.)

Not sure if it's a bug or feature; while testing yargs parsers, something is messing with the parser configuration so that, nothing from *commands*  directories gets loaded into the parser.
How can I test my parser using Jest? Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am running into a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(